# Passing a derived class to a web service method, as the base class

Tags: c#, web-services, tostring, derived-class

I have a C# class imported from a web service. Due to debugging issues and arrays, I needed this class to have a `ToString()` override or `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`, and the only way I found was adding the former to a derived class:

```
class ExtWebServiceDataClass: WebServiceDataClass
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("stuff");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the webservice methods demand an array of base objects and do not accept an array of derived objects (XML serialization error):

> System.InvalidOperationException: Error generating the XML document.
>
> → System.InvalidOprrationException: The type ExtWebServiceDataClass was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

Is there any way to make it accept it from the client side? An attribute that says `it's just like the base class, just serialize it as such`?

Or an easy way to mass-convert from the derived class to the base class?

Or more simply, another way to have a `ToString` override or `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` on the client side?

Comment: What *exactly* is the serialization error?

Comment: I would personally suggest that you delete this question, and ask a more detailed one when you're back at work. Otherwise we'll quite possibly be guessing.

Comment: I have reproduced the error at home and added the error message.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to send a type defined on the client to the server - and have your ToString override execute on the server?  Or is the ToString override just for client side debugging?

Comment: The ToString override is just for client-side debugging.

Comment: Is `WebServiceDataClass` declared as a `partial class` in a generated file? If so, you can define your `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` in another file.

Comment: @TimS. Ooh, you're right. So very right, it's is indeed declared as `partial`, so I could add my `ToString` override (and anything else I please) to it. Please repost your comment as an answer so I can award you the bounty.

Comment: You could use AutoMapper to map from the derived class to the base class. Should solve your problem although not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebServiceDataClass` is declared as a `partial class` in a generated file (like most generated classes are). You can define your [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx) or `ToString` in another file in the same project, like so:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("MyString")]
public partial class WebServiceDataClass
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, at least for my "Application" and "DLL" clients. Less so for website clients (their web references are considered separate assemblies) but I can move the code in question to a DLL and it works.